# What are some examples of MediaController commands?

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-mediasession, notification-listener

Checking out the [MediaController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController) documentation, I noticed that there is a function called [sendCommand(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver)), which requires three parameters:

- command: String;
- args: Bundle;
- cb: ResultReceiver.

But examples of how to use that method are *nowhere to be found*.

---

**What are the available `MediaController#sendCommand(...)` default commands and acceptable argument keys and values types?**

---

For example, checking [PlaybackState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/PlaybackState) documentation, we can find a constant called [`ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/PlaybackState.html#ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID) which description is as follows:

> Indicates this session supports the play from media id command

This leads us to think that `MediaController#sendCommand(...)` is able to change a `MediaSession`'s current media by sending it the media ID. How can we do it?
*It's known that Google Play Music App's MediaController shares its Media Queue through [`MediaController#getQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html#getQueue()) function.*

Answer (score 0):

You can find Commands constants in MediaControllerCompat.

They actually are:

```
public static final String COMMAND_GET_EXTRA_BINDER =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.GET_EXTRA_BINDER";

public static final String COMMAND_ADD_QUEUE_ITEM =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.ADD_QUEUE_ITEM";

public static final String COMMAND_ADD_QUEUE_ITEM_AT =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.ADD_QUEUE_ITEM_AT";

public static final String COMMAND_REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM";

public static final String COMMAND_REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM_AT =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM_AT";

public static final String COMMAND_ARGUMENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION =
       "android.support.v4.media.session.command.ARGUMENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION";

public static final String COMMAND_ARGUMENT_INDEX =
        "android.support.v4.media.session.command.ARGUMENT_INDEX";
```

For some basic usage samples u can check out its methods, like:

```
    @Override
    public void removeQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat description) {
        long flags = getFlags();
        if ((flags & MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_QUEUE_COMMANDS) == 0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "This session doesn't support queue management operations");
        }
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putParcelable(COMMAND_ARGUMENT_MEDIA_DESCRIPTION, description);
        sendCommand(COMMAND_REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM, params, null);
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the constants you've listed out are marked as hidden with the `@hide` annotation: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:media/src/main/java/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.java;bpv=0;l=103-145

Comment: Yes, they are. If take a look at MediaSessionConnector.QueueEditor. U can see that, if u use COMMAND_REMOVE_QUEUE_ITEM, QueueEditor.onRemoveQueueItem will be called. And if u use ur own command, then QueueEditor.onCommand will be called. So these are just some built in examples. And if u wanna use onCommand, u need to use ur own Commands, not those.